# How can I get 3 working displays with Intel graphics?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, lenovo, thinkpad

I have an up-to-date 17.04 on my Lenovo thinkpad t530. I am trying to have 3 working displays using the integrated Intel graphics video controller.

The 3 displays are the integrated screen plus two external monitors, one connected on the VGA port, the other on the mini-displayport.

The following configurations are working:

- the integrated screen + one external (whichever it is)
- the two external monitors (integrated one is off)

To enable the 3 displays, I'm trying:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output LVDS-1 --primary --mode 1600x900 --pos 3840x180 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
```

which results in:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

(it may be crtc 0 or crtc 2, depending on which displays are currently on)

Before asking, I've done some searches, which led me onto this page https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1215449 
It makes me belive that it is possible to have 3 working displays with this setup but I can't succed.

What can I do?

EDIT 20170911
from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005556.html it is confirmed that intel HD graphics 4000 supports 3 simultaneous displays, at least with some limitations I still need to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Often the intergrated graphics card only supports 2 active displays even though there are three ports.To get a third display you need a second graphics card.

Comment: Agreed, but my readings let me think it is possible with the "Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller" embedded into the thinkpad t530. I think I missed something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ARandR.
I have managed to use three displays on Ubuntu 18.04 by making them active in the Outputs menu:

[image: ARandR UI]

Without ARandR, only two displays worked. After connecting the third one, only the primary display was working.